# rails c throws error bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.8 (Gem::Exception)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to open rails console in production mode and it throws below error,

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': 
    can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.8 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

I have not used rvm. Other commands like `rake:xyz` runs properly. Output of `$gem env` is as follows,

**RubyGems Environment:**

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

Please let me know what needs to be. I cannot go for bundle install, etc as its production env and there are few tasks running. I dont want to break existing tasks / processes

Comment: Looks like you don't have rails installed.

Comment: It Worked...had to use RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

Answer (score 1):

It worked by using,

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

Answer (score 0):

Being a beginner,I have tried the same on my system and I got into the rails console.In fact my `gem env` resulted in

```
    RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
    - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
      - ruby
      - x86_64-linux
    - GEM PATHS:
       - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
       - /home/mmohan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:
       - :update_sources => true
       - :verbose => true
       - :benchmark => false
       - :backtrace => false
       - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - REMOTE SOURCES:
       - http://rubygems.org/
```

On reading the error, gem is found to be outdated. The best method to tackle it is by updating gem to latest one. If for assistance, check thishttp://www.coval.nl/blog/?p=18